# Object field not modified as wanted after a promise.then and before a res.send

Tags: node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js, javascript-objects

## Summarize the problem

I'm trying to change some fields of a JSON object but the result I have when I console.log or res.send is not the one expected

## What I already tried

1. Promises with then
2. Promises with async/await
3. Tried to change the fields using :

```
user2 = {
    ...user,
    newFiels : 'newfiled',
}
```

4. Tried to change the object with Object.assign(...)
5. Debug in VS Code : **which actually shows the expected result (only in the debugger), but not when I console.log...**

## Show some code

I'm using Sequelize, and the field "**role**" is not directly on the table "**Users**". Therefore, I use and **include** (which does a JOIN) to get the role :

1. Find the user
2. Determine if he is a technician or not
3. According to 2) add the role as a new field
4. Put the user (which has now the correct syntax) in the response.userInfo field
5. Send the data back

```
// in login function 

let response = {
    status: "NotOK",
    userInfo: {
      username: null,
      nom: null,
      prenom: null,
      role: null,
    },
    infoMsg: null,
    error: false,
    errorMsg: null,
  }

  const usernameInput = req.query.username;
  const passwordInput = req.query.password;


// 1)
Utilisateurs.findOne({
    attributes: ['username', 'nom', 'prenom'],
    include: [
      { model: Techniciens },
      { model: Magasiniers },
    ],
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [
        { username: usernameInput },
        { password: passwordInput },
      ],
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        // 2) and 3)
        if (user.technicien != null) {
          user.role = 'technicien';
        } else {
          user.role = 'magasinier';
        }

        // 4)
        response.userInfo = user;
        response.status = 'OK'
        response.infoMsg = "User found !"
        console.log(`response : ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        // 5)
        res.send(response);
        return;
      } else {
        // ...
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // ...
    });
```

Everything seems to work except **4)**, and I don't know why

## Describe expected and actual results

### Expected results

I'm doing the backend on a project and I was asked to give an object of this format (see **Response**) :

```
Description: authenticate the user

Body content  : 
{
   "username" : "theUsername",
   "password" : "thePassword"
}

Response : 
{
   "status" : "OK/NotOK",
   "userInfo" : {
      "username" : "theUsername",
      "nom" : "theName",
      "prenom" : "theLastName",
      "role" : "magasinier/technicien"
   },
   "infoMsg": "infomsg",
   "error": true/false,
   "errorMsg": "errmsg"
}
```

### Actual results

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "userInfo":{
      "username":"davalres",
      "nom":"Alvarez",
      "prenom":"David",
      "technicien":null,
      "magasinier":{
         "username":"davalres"
      }
   },
   "infoMsg":"User found !",
   "error":false,
   "errorMsg":null
}
```

### What I can see in the debugger before "**Actual results**"

[image: debugger image]
As you can see, all the fields I want are here. Maybe I'm confusing and I shouldn't have all those fields like `__eagerlyLoadedAssociations`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` object you get is a model instance, so I would not embed such object inside your own response object, nor modify it directly, as the model might eventually revert unsaved changes you made to it.

Instead get a clean copy of the information you need, by calling `.get({plain:true})` on it. I would personally also keep the scope of `response` local to the `then` callback (and create another in the `catch` callback if needed):

```
if (user) {
    let response = {
        status: "OK",
        userInfo: {
            ...user.get({plain:true}),
            role: user.technicien ? 'technicien' : 'magasinier';
        },
        infoMsg: "User found",
        error: false,
        errorMsg: null,
    };
    console.log(`response : ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
    res.send(response);
    return;
} else //....
```